# Java Thread waits forever on Async Task

Tags: java, multithreading, android-asynctask, firebase, firebase-authentication

The object returned by `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` is a `Task<AuthResult>` which I could set a `onSuccess` or `onFailure` callback for; but the main issue is, I need the main thread here to ***wait*** on this process to finish before moving to the next step of the process. The create part ***is*** working, but when the thread does finally finish, the Task object says success is false and returns, which also confuses me since it did successfully create a user.

```
if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() == null) {
    final Task<AuthResult> resultTask = firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
            "email@address.com",
            "tester1234");
    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(!resultTask.isComplete()) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    });
    thread.start();
    thread.join(10000);
    if(!resultTask.isSuccessful())
        return false;
}
```

And trying this method below only hangs indefinitely:

```
if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() == null) {
    final CountDownLatch countDownLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);
    firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
            "email@address.com",
            "test1234")
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        countDownLatch.countDown();
                    }
                });
    countDownLatch.await();
}
```

Comment: where do you launch/execute your task?

Comment: if you don't launch your task, it will indeed never get completed, makes sense WDYT?

Comment: @NicolasFilotto the task is started by the `createUserWithEmailAndPassword`

Comment: if so show us the content of createUserWithEmailAndPassword because what we have so far is not helpful

Comment: @NicolasFilotto here is as much as I get without digging into the Firebase  code http://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth.html#createUserWithEmailAndPassword(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String

Comment: Is there a possibility that having the main thread wait is just bad practice? (I mean it is the ui thread after-all, an unresponsive app just isn't good to have; maybe need to rethink the implementation, unless anyone has a solution for this)

Comment: I don't know Firebase so I can't help a lot, the only thing that I can tell you is the fact that your second approach is clearly the best, now the question is why the task is obviously never executed? Debug to know

Comment: or maybe the task is executed but for some reason it is very slow?

Comment: @NicolasFilotto figured it out; needed to wrap the above code in another thread/asynctask. The `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` needs the main thread available; so blocking until it finishes will never happen.

Comment: good news, I guess you can answer to your own question then

Answer (score 0):

I have not worked on Firebase APIs, but to debug this question, I have gone through the APIs to understand a bit, Even I agree that at least above CountDownLatch logic should work.

I saw that there are two callbacks are there related to task completion:

1. `public Task<TResult> addOnCompleteListener (OnCompleteListener<TResult> listener)`
2. `public abstract Task<TResult> addOnSuccessListener (OnSuccessListener<? super TResult> listener)`

One callback API is for failure case as well:

```
public abstract Task<TResult> addOnFailureListener (OnFailureListener listener)
```

So at this point of time, my suggestion is to use all the three callbacks to debug that which callback is actually executed: We can change the code as below to debug:

```
     firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
            "email@address.com",
            "test1234")
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        countDownLatch.countDown();
                    }
                }
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(TResult result) {
                        countDownLatch.countDown();
                    }
                }
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Exception ex) {
                        countDownLatch.countDown();
                    }
                });

    countDownLatch.await();
```

All the listener will be called on main application thread.
This answer is based on this [link](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Task#inherited-method-summary). I will be happy If it helps you. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this was to not block the main thread; using a `CountDownLatch` or any other waiting mechanism is fine ONLY if the mechanism is wrapped in an `AsyncTask` or another thread of its own. This ultimately meant for me rewriting my code to make my app more responsive.